# Remove class using jquery on a certain condition for propery alignment of submenus

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I need to remove a certain css class from `.nav`, so that it comes up properly. Right now its behaviour is unexpected based on different screen sizes.

Fiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/wPWDm/6/)

[Demo View](http://fiddle.jshell.net/wPWDm/6/show/#)

You will notice that the drop-down sub-menus don't show up properly. I want the dropdown to show on right side of dropdown, when it has enough space on the right, and on the left side of dropdown, when it has less space based on the `<div class="main-wrapper">` width, which is 1000px wide.

I tried to fix it with following code but it is not working properly:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".nav").on("mouseenter", " > li", function(){

        /*if dropdown is likely to go out of parent nav then right align it :) */
        if (($(this).offset().left) + 200 > $('.menu-wrapper').width()) {
            $(this).find(".dropdown").addClass("dropdown-last");
        }
        if($(this).hasClass("has-panel")){
           // $(this).find(".dropdown").removeClass("dropdown-last");
            //alert('has class');
        }
        else
        {
        //alert('has no class');
        }
    });

    /* if dropdnw*/
    $(".dropdown").each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        if($this.find(".dd-panel").length > 0){
            $this.addClass('has-panel');

        }


        if($this.find(".dd-panel").length = 1){
           $(".dropdown").css( "min-height", "80px" );
        }
    });
});
```

On debug, it shows the following as a div class `dropdown has-panel dropdown-last` if it div with has class `has-panel` and one which doesnt have mega menu for it show class as `dropdown dropdown-last`. I was trying to check using jQuery, to see if the element has the class or not. If it has the class `has-panel`, then do nothing and if it doesn't have the class `has-panel`, then I need to remove the class `dropdown-last` from the same element which is not working with following code:

```
if($(this).hasClass("has-panel")){
   // $(this).find(".dropdown").removeClass("dropdown-last");
    alert('has class');
}
else
{
//alert('has no class');
}
```

Comment: why are you using window.load and document.ready? you need to understand the difference. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8562609/should-i-use-window-load-or-document-ready-jquery using document.ready after window.load will not work as window.load is fired after document.ready

Comment: I dont need it actually...

Comment: Why don't you need it? I agree with @MikeOram you DO need it.

Answer (score 0):

remove `$(window).load(function(){}` and it will work

Answer (score 0):

Solved using code

```
    if( $(this).find(".dropdown").hasClass("has-panel")){
       // $(this).find(".dropdown").removeClass("dropdown-last");
        //alert('has class');
    }
    else
    {
    //alert('has no class');
     $(this).find(".dropdown").removeClass("dropdown-last");
    }
```