# Change style on page load with a <select>

Tags: jquery

I have this piece of js code allowing me, on a `<select>` change, change the table theme color.

How can I execute this jQuery when the page loads and when a `<option>` of `<select>` is already selected ?

Thanks.

## My HTML:

```
<select name="HOT_ColorsTheme" id="HOT_ColorsTheme" class="form-control">
    <option value="A">Thème A</option>
    <option value="B" selected>Thème B</option>
</select>
```

---

## My JS:

```
<script>
$("#HOT_ColorsTheme").on('change', function() {
    var sel = $('#HOT_ColorsTheme').val();
     if (sel=='A') {
             $(".Today").css({'background' : '#fe0002', 'color' : '#000000'});
    }
     if (sel=='B') {
             $(".Today").css({'background' : '#dedede', 'color' : '#000000'});
    }
});     
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function:

```
function changeColor() {
    var sel = $('#HOT_ColorsTheme').val();
    if (sel=='A') {
         $(".Today").css({'background' : '#fe0002', 'color' : '#000000'});
    }
    if (sel=='B') {
         $(".Today").css({'background' : '#dedede', 'color' : '#000000'});
    }
}
```

And then:

```
<script>
    $("#HOT_ColorsTheme").on('change', changeColor);
    $(document).ready(function() {
        changeColor();
    });
</script>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gfg/yjNP4/1/

Comment: How is this different from my answer?

Comment: I didn't see previous answer, but braces in onchange won't work

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function changeScheme(){
   var sel = $('#HOT_ColorsTheme').val();
   if (sel=='A') {
      $(".Today").css({'background' : '#fe0002', 'color' : '#000000'});
   }
   if (sel=='B') {
      $(".Today").css({'background' : '#dedede', 'color' : '#000000'});
   }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
   changeScheme();
   $("#HOT_ColorsTheme").on('change', changeScheme());
});
```

Comment: The OP said "When the page is load" so Document.ready is not when the page is load [document.ready vs window.load] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8562609/should-i-use-window-load-or-document-ready-jquery)

Comment: @Freak_Droid: I believe that with OP's current knowledge of JS and English, it's difficult to say what he wants. I believe this answer is correct. (Except his second comment, for which I'm going to edit my answer now).

Comment: @Richard Rodriguez: I'm french.

Answer (score 0):

you can just write a single additional line at the end of `$(function(){ ---- });` (i.e. document ready code)

```
$(function(){
--
----- your other js code if any
--
    // triggering the change event on the select by referring its id
    $('#HOT_ColorsTheme').trigger('change');
});
```

Assuming your color changing code is working properly, 
It will just trigger the change event, when your document will be ready, and when the change event is triggered, your above function is there to handle the event.