# javascript prop() not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, height

I have a problem with `IE8` ,I am getting the `height` of the object 0. It works fine in `FF` and `chrome`.

```
    var value = obj.prop("height");
```

`prop()` doesnot work with `IE` or, the height is 0 because the obj is a hidden image tag.
Any help?

Comment: r u able to get the height of visible image on IE?

Comment: what is obj? I don't think prop is a vanilla javascript function

Comment: If the element has a `prop` attribute, you should use `.attr()`, not `.prop()`. And if you want to get the calculated height, you should use `.height()`.

Comment: @kennypu   obj is the id of the image tag ..

Comment: you might want to show relevant HTML. is there a reason you are using prop() to get height? you can just use .height()

Comment: if i use obj.height() , i get the value 0 :-/

Comment: If the object is an image, you will need to make sure the image has finished loading BEFORE you request it's height.  The only way to know for sure that the image has finished loading is to either check the `.complete` property or set an `onload` handler so you get notified when it finishes loading.  The image height is simply not known until the browser has finished downloading the image.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that you are trying get the height attribute from your img tag that look something like this.

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x350" width="350" height="350" style="display:none;">
```

Note the `width` and `height` attribute.

If you're trying to get the height attribute value in the img tag, try using [`.attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) like so

```
var value = obj.attr("height");
```

Another note is that the image might not be loaded and as a result is acting weird on IE8. Try to make sure the image is loaded before getting the height.

For this matter, see [explanation about document.ready and window.load](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8562885/685326).

However, as many have said, you should be using `.height()` to get the height of an element.

Answer (score -1):

.prop is a jquery function
you need to include jquery in your page

```
http://api.jquery.com/prop/
```

for chrome and firefox you might have it it your browser's cache
i think thats wht its working...

Comment: I wouldn't post an answer, as there are still too many unknowns. you are assuming 1. he is using jquery and 2. if he is, that he doesn't have it included. we don't know that yet.

Comment: I've included jquery too.

Comment: @kennypu If it works fine on FF and Chrome, it should be jQuery. There isn't `.prop()` method in JavaScript.

Comment: i dont get any errors in FF , it works fine. There are no errors in IE console too, but the height is 0.

Comment: @Vidia you should mention jQuery then, as .prop() is not from javascript.

Comment: check your docype see if its valid ! its IE

Comment: @Vidia Which jQuery version are you using? The result isn't wrong. When an element is hidden, the height is in fact 0. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @josephting i'm using jquery 1.10 , if the element height is 0 for hidden objects , why did the same work in FF and chrome ? i dont get whats wrong with IE

Comment: @Vidia Did you mean FF and Chrome returned the correct height? When did you run this code - `var value = obj.prop("height");`? `$(document).ready()`? `$(window).load()`?

Comment: Did you use js code to hide the image tag or just set it in html code?